# spaces in end tags

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem for loading xml in c #.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlText = File.ReadAllText("D:\\webservice_aspnet\\novo2.xml");
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
```

Above do loading the file.

Original file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teste>
<abc xmlns="xxx"/>
</teste>
```

When I try doc.InnerXml, and create a xml file, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teste>
<abc xmlns="xxx" />
</teste>
```

See that a space was added here:

```
<abc xmlns="xxx" />
```

at the end of the tag. I know this does not alter the structure of the file, however I have a validation algorithm that file and I can not change anything or add a space.

I do not want to replace to fix this, because they are giants and files can lose information.

Anyone know how I can generate the identical file?

Comment: If there isn't a parameter on the specific XML serializer implementation you're using which controls that, you'll need to replace or modify that serializer. However, this is likely to only be the tip of the iceberg -- there are other ways that the same XML infoset can have multiple serialized forms, and the infoset doesn't necessarily record all the information required to reconstruct those exactly as they came in.

I really, _REALLY_ recommend that you fix your validation algorithm.

Comment: Well, if you are validating the xml as "string" then you are gonna end up with different problems. I would suggest that you validate it with a schema may be !

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading XML using a parser (perhaps a home-brew parser) than can't handle all legal XML syntax, then you are storing up trouble, and your name will be cursed by anyone who inherits your code. Don't do it.

Don't try to fix the XML generation code to generate the subset of XML that your parser can handle. Fix your parser.

One way to fix your parser might be to add an XML canonicalization step as the first thing it does; canonicalization generates a well defined subset of XML that might (if you're lucky) correspond to the subset that your home-brew parser understands.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try doc.Load(file) instead of doc.LoadXml(file).

Answer (score 0):

Please try just using `Replace` function:

```
string YourXML=SomexmlContent;
string result=YourXML.Replace(" />","/>");
```

Hope this helps!